# When translating a node, can I avoid copying the default value from the original language

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n

Just a little background:  I've got a set of paragraphs fields that I need to be able to translate, and given the limitations on translation with paragraphs, I've come up with the idea, that it may just be best to create a new node of a new content type (for holding the paragraphs fields) for each language of the main node.  I would then use Inline Entity Form to bring those fields into my main node.

The problem I run into is that translation copies the value from the original language when I create a translation.  Most of the time this is desirable, but in this case, it means that all languages get the same referenced node, when I specifically want them all to have their own new node.

Is there any way to suppress the value copy functionality for a specific field when translating?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unset the field values in a [hook_ENTITY_TYPE_translation_create](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_ENTITY_TYPE_translation_create/8.7.x):

```
use Drupal\node\NodeInterface;

/**
 * Implements hook_ENTITY_TYPE_translation_create().
 */
function mymodule_node_translation_create(Nodeinterface $translation) {
  if ($translation->getType() == 'product') {
    unset($translation->body);
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the slow reply to this.  I'm finding that $translation's structure is not as simple as indicated here, and am trying to figure out what should be unset to allow me to prevent inline entity form from getting a default node to work with.

Comment: This code examples avoids copying the default value from the original language for the field `body`. You only need to replace this with your field name `unset($translation->field_example);` and adjust the content type and it should work.

Comment: I guess I am not familiar enough with Drupal 8 OO coding.  I tried inspecting $translation with xdebug, and there must be some getter and setter magic happening that I didn't account for.  It appears to work very well.  Thank you!

Comment: it doesn't work for paragraphs. In hook `Nodeinterface` is changed with `EntityInterface`

Comment: @Sharique, the code example needs Nodeinterface because of getType(). If the argument is declared more generic you can't use a more specific method, at least not in an IDE.